# Zagier's algebraicity of singular moduli

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, j-invariant

Let $\mathcal M_m\subset M(2,\mathbb Z)$ be the set matrices with determinant $n$. The modular group $\Gamma$ acts on $\mathcal M_m$ from the left and we have the following finite set as a set of representatives of the orbits of this action

$$\mathcal M_n^*=\bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}:ad=m,0\leq b\leq d\bigg\rbrace.$$

Consider the modular equation
$$\Phi_m(X,j(z))=\prod_{M\in\mathcal M_m^*}\left(X-j(Mz)\right).$$
It is straightforward to prove that this is actually a polynomial in two variables $\Phi_m(X,Y)$. Zagier shows in [his notes, p. 71](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf), that the leading coefficient of $\Phi_m(X,X)$ is invertible if $m$ is not a square. He also demonstrates that $j(z)$ is a root of $\Phi_m(X,X)$ if and only if $z$ is fixed by some matrix $M$ with determinant $m$.

Zagier proceeds to show that for $z\in\mathfrak H$ a complex multiplication point of discriminat D, i.e. $Az^2+Bz+C=0$, $D=B^2-4AC$, $(A,B,C)=1$ the folowing two statements are equivalent:

1. There is a matrix $M$ with determinant $m$ fixing $z$.
2. We can find $\lambda\in\mathcal O_D$ such that the norm $N(\lambda)=m$.

Here $\mathcal O_D$ is the unique quadratic order with discriminant $D$.

The important consequence is that, given a CM point $z$, then the set of $m$ with the property that $\Phi_m(j(z),j(z))=0$ depends only on the disriminant $D$, not on $z$ itself.

Therefore we can relate this with the class number $h(D)$. If $z_1,...,z_{h(D)}$ are the inequivalent points pertaining to the discriminat $D$ then either all of these points are roots of a given modular equation $\Phi_m(X,X)$ or none are. Let 
$$H_D(X)=\prod_{i=1}^{h(D)}\left(X-z_i\right).$$

Zagier now claims 
$$\Phi_m(X,X)=\pm\prod_{D<0}H_D(X)^{r_D(m)/w_D},\label{1}\tag{1}$$
if $m$ is not a square. Here is
$$r_D(m)=\#\lbrace (t,u)\in \mathbb Z^2:t^2-D^2u^2=4m\rbrace=\#\lbrace \lambda\in \mathcal O_D: N(\lambda)=m\rbrace,$$
$$w_D=\# \text{ number of units in }\mathcal O_D.
$$
However, Zagier is here very brief and I do not understand how he arrived at \eqref{1}. **Why should the formula \eqref{1} hold?** Note that if $F(a,a)=0$ then the multiplicity of $a$ as a root of $F(X,a)$ and $F(X,X)$ may differ.

Let $D$ be a discriminant. Then by a suitable choice of elements $\lambda\in\mathcal O_D$ we should be able to achieve that $H_D(X)$ is the greatest common divisor of finitely many modular equations. This would show that the coefficients of $H_D(X)$ were rational. **How to do this? How to choose the norms?** (Cf. Zagier's article for more details.)